# I'm trying to install the MySQL connector on a windows 7 systembut it doesn't show up in the ODBC add window

Tags: mysql, windows-7, installation, odbc, mysql-odbc-connector

This is under Windows 7 64 bit. I downloaded the 64 bit drivers and as a matter of fact I tried all the windows drivers(uninstalling the previous ones first though). But when I try to configure a new ODBC connection the MySQL driver doesn't show up.

Do I need to install some other package before I can get the connector to work? Like MDAC or .NET or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running the ODBC from "C:\Windows\SysWOW64" instead of from "C:\Windows\System32".

Answer (score 14):

The key question is whether your ODBC client executable -- the thing that's going to load the driver library and use the data -- is 32-bit or 64-bit.  64-bit Windows (XP, Vista, 7, 8, Server 2003, Server 2008, and all other variants to date) supports both 32-bit and 64-bit binary executables/libraries.  32-bit executables (usually found in `Program Files (x86)`) can only use 32-bit drivers; 64-bit executables (usually found in `Program Files`) can only use 64-bit drivers.

Once you've figured that part out, you have to install a matching 32-bit or 64-bit driver for MySQL, and configure it with the right ODBC Administrator.  The 32-bit ODBC Administrator is counterintuitively found at `C:\Windows\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe`, and the 64-bit ODBC Administrator is likewise counterintuitively found at `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe`.  (Yes, both are named `odbcad32` and the directory names suggest the other bitness -- but what I've just said is accurate.)

For more on this, you can read [the article](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin) posted on my [employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/)'s website

Note that for added fun, Microsoft's ODBC driver manager (the MDAC) has a bug in that [it shows 32-bit User DSNs to 64-bit client executables (including the Administrator), and it shows 64-bit User DSNs to 32-bit client executables (again, including the Administrator)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976) -- even though these mis-matches cannot work together.  For this reason, I strongly recommend using *only* System DSNs in any environment that may have a mix of 32-bit and 64-bit executables/drivers/DSNs.

Comment: But shouldn't the 32bit MySQL driver show up using C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe if I installed the 32bit driver? 

Thanks

Pete

Comment: No -- the System32\odbcad32.exe is the 64-bit Administrator, and will only work against 64-bit drivers.  This is where 64-bit drivers will show up.

The SysWow64\odbcad32.exe is the 32-bit Administrator, which must be used against 32-bit drivers.  This is where 32-bit drivers will show up.

Microsoft has a few KB articles about this.  I've added a link to one of them above.

Comment: This answer is more complete than the accepted one and should be the top answer.

Comment: @user2713461 broke my answer, by reversing the 32-bit and 64-bit paths.  They were correct before that edit was applied, and I am correcting them again now.  The 32-bit Administrator *IS* found in SysWow64, and the 64-bit Administrator *IS* found in System32.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run 32 bit in WIN 7:
Download 32 bit version ZIP (f.e. mysql-connector-odbc-noinstall-5.1.13-win32)
Run Install.bat
Open c:\Windows\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe
In User DSN Add and you can choose from 32 bit version drivers

Answer (score 1):

"The 32-bit Administrator IS found in SysWow64, and the 64-bit Administrator IS found in System32. –  TallTed May 5 '14 at 16:19"

So I ended hell week by following Ted's simple statement.  I opened this well-concealed 32 bit exe and Wah La! All the drivers I couldn't see till then were ready and willing to go to work.  They had even survived several faux de-installs!

I'm on an iMac running Windows 7 Ultimate on Parallels 10.  The MS Access app was built on a Win7 only machine which I was able to link to MySQL by virtue of the random monkey toolset.  I was not so lucky on this machine.  If Ted's factoid will work on this IMac, it will work anywhere.

btw: It turns out I do have both 32 and 64 bit drivers, Unicode, etc--all three.  I am not prepared to sort that one out. :0

Answer (score -1):

Access 2013 wouldn't show it until I installed both the 32 bit and 64 bit drivers and then exited and restarted Access.